# getting "TypeError: fetch failed" while using @microsoft-graph-client in nodejs within proxy env

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

we are using `msal-node` and `@microsoft-graph-client` and `node version is 20.9` within VPN and facing `typeError:fetch failed` while making graph api call ,when we execute the code outside vpn it works fine, and we are getting the token from msal-node even with vpn but the graph api is not working with VPN connected

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
let groupid="";
let driveitemid="";
var msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
MicrosoftGraph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
 const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
 const fetch = require('node-fetch-with-proxy');
 const networkClient={
 sendGetRequestAsync:async function (url, options) {
   const response = await fetch(url, options);
   const json = await response.json();
   const headers = response.headers.raw();
   return {
     headers: Object.create(Object.prototype, headers),
     body: json,
     status: response.status
   }
 }, 
 sendPostRequestAsync:async function (url, options) {
   const sendingOptions = options || {};
   sendingOptions.method = 'post';
   const response = await fetch(url, sendingOptions);
   const json = await response.json()
   const headers = response.headers.raw();
   return {
     headers: Object.create(Object.prototype, headers),
     body: json,
     status: response.status,
     agent:sendingOptions.agent
   }
 
 }}
const agent = new HttpsProxyAgent.HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.http_proxy);
 //require("isomorphic-fetch");

const config = require(`./config/AAD.json`);
async function getClientCredentialsToken(cca) {
    
    const clientCredentialRequest = {
        scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],     
        skipCache: true,
    };
 return   await  cca
        .acquireTokenByClientCredential(clientCredentialRequest)
        .then((response) => {
          
            console.log("Response: ", response);
            return response;
        
        }).catch((error) => {
           
             console.log(error);
        });
}
async function callGraph(accessToken)
{
  
    console.log(agent);
    var client =await MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({     
       debugLogging: false,    
       authProvider: function(authDone) {
         authDone(null, accessToken);
       },
       fetchOptions: {
        //agent: prxyagent
      },
     });

let url=`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupid}/drive/items/${driveitemid}?$expand=thumbnails`
try {
result=await client.api(url).get();
console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
}
let main=async()=>{
       const clientConfig = {
        auth: config.authOptions,
        system: {
           networkClient: networkClient          
            }       
    };
    const confidentialClientApplication = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(clientConfig);
 let tokenresponse=await  getClientCredentialsToken(confidentialClientApplication);
   if(tokenresponse.accessToken)
   {
    callGraph(tokenresponse.accessToken);
   }
};
main();
```

but we are getting the accesstoken from msal-node but the graph api throws
`TypeError: fetch failed     at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   statusCode: -1,   code: 'TypeError',`